# What if we change the def of limit as following

Tags: calculus

In definition of limits why can't we have " there exist delta for all epsilon" instead of  " for all epsilon there exist delta"

Comment: because it leads to a different notions, and a useless one in fact.

Comment: aren't those statements equivalent?

Comment: thanks for your response....can you clarify by some example? because the statements  "there exist delta for all epsilon" and "for all epsilon there exist delta" seems to be same

Comment: Nay. What you propose would imply the function is eventually constant on an interval.

Comment: See 'For any natural number $X$ there exists natural $G$ such that $G>X$.' Quite obviously true, isn't it? See now 'There exists a natural number $G$ such that for any natural $X$, $G>X$.' Does this statement seem equivalent to the previous one...?

Comment: There is a subtle difference between "there exists Y for all X.." and "there exists Y _such that_ for all X..". The first phrase is ambiguous, and will often mean the same as "for all X there exists Y". Example "there exists a nontrivial solution to every linear homogeneous system with more unknowns than equations". However the second possibility unambiguously means something very different; the "such that" is significant here. Nobody would say "there exists a nontrivial solution such that it solves every linear homogeneous system with more unknowns than equations". Please clarify the question

Answer (score 9):

"For any $\epsilon$, there exists a $\delta$" means that *whenever* you get an $\epsilon$, it's possible to find *some* $\delta$ that makes it work.

"There exists a $\delta$ such that for any $\epsilon$" means that there is *one, single* $\delta$ that works no matter what $\epsilon$ might be.

An analogy might do: Take the statement "For any man, there is a woman that is meant for him". It is not an outrageous statement. Some might contest it, but the idea has been there for centuries, and many people will defend its truth to their dying breath.

The statement "There is a woman, such that for any man, she is meant for him", on the other hand, implies that there is one woman somewhere that is everyone's future wife (poor girl). I think you will have to look hard to find anyone who actually believes this.

Answer (score 0):

But a necessary (though not sufficient) condition for that to happen is that $f$ must be *uniformly* continuous, and not just continuous; otherwise,$\delta$ is a function of $\epsilon $

Comment: thanks for response... can you give some example ?

Comment: Sure, try $f(x)=x^2$, and $\epsilon=1$. Then , at $x=0, \delta=1$ will wok, but $\delta=1$ will not work at $x=2$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the idea of the limit is that "we can make $f(x)$ arbitrarily close to $L$, by making $x$ sufficiently close to $a$". In other words, instead of analyzing the domain and seeing what happens in the range, we analyze the range, and try to modify the domain appropriately. So we say "for all $\epsilon$ (Range) there exists a $\delta$ (Domain)" instead of vice versa.

Comment: thanks for your response ... but that's how it is written in book... what if we  analyze another way and try to see that other def is same as the usual one given in books

Comment: @saqib That's the way they did it before. But that proved insufficient. Read more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#History

Answer (score 0):

I'll work a similar concept: **Continuity.**

If we have in the definition "there exists a delta such that for all epsilon", then a lot of intuitively "continuous" functions (those whose graph can be drawn without raising the pencil) wouldn't be continuous.

For instance, take the identity function $f(x)=x$ defined on $\mathbb R$, then $f$ is continuous at $0$ in the intuitive way but not with the "new" definition since it's not true that there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for every $\varepsilon>0$ (whatever you choose), if $|x|<\delta$ then $|f(x)|=|x|<\varepsilon$ (if such a $\delta$ exists, then take $x=\varepsilon=\delta/2$, we have $|x|<\delta$ but $|f(x)|=|x|\nless \varepsilon$).

Comment: That's not true. There is an $|x|<\delta$ such that $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$. In fact, for any $\epsilon$ there exists a $\delta = \epsilon$ that would satisfy that.

Comment: Tell if this statement is true: $\exists \delta_0>0: \forall \varepsilon>0: |x|<\delta_0 \implies |f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: without symbolic logic plz.

Comment: What you wrote is right: For every epsilon there exists a delta, that's the classic (and correct one) definition of continuity. Notice that your $\delta$ depends on $\varepsilon$. What I'm arguing is that there can't exist a FIXED $\delta$ that works for all $\varepsilon$.

Comment: that's the definition of the limit. But you can also reverse it and say that for any $\delta$ there is an $\epsilon$ such that ... provided $L+\delta$ and $L-\delta \in$ Domain $f$.

Comment: @SolidSnake are you trying to say that delta changes when ever we change epsilon as they both are same in this case so delta won't remain fixed ?

Comment: @saqib Yes, $\delta$ ${\it may}$ vary as $\varepsilon$ does. In this case, $\delta$ can't stay fixed, I've added an explanation of this fact on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

‘There exists a $\delta>0$ such that for *all* $\varepsilon>0$, if $\,\lvert x-x_0\rvert <\delta$, then $\,\lvert f(x)-\ell\rvert<\varepsilon$’

implies that $f(x)-\ell=0$, i. e. $f(x)=\ell\,$ as soon as $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$.

Comment: why will f(x) - l =0

Comment: Which nonnegative numbers do you know  that are less than *any* positive number?

Comment: but epsilon needs to be positive ..you can't take it 0

Comment: Let me be more concete: which non-negative numbers are less than $10^{-1}, 10^{-2},10^{-3}, \dots, 10^{-n}, \dots$ (all of these numbers simultaneously)?